# losing functions when convert in a dropdown selection

Tags: php, twig, e-commerce

I have an ecommerce based on twig and in this moment my product variables looks like this:

[How the varibles looks currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8XBD.png)

This image looks like that using this code:

```
<ul class="variants dropMenu">
        {% for variant in product.variants%}
        <li class="{% if not variant.stock.available %}unavailable{% elseif variant.id == product.vid %}selected{% elseif variant.id != product.vid%}not-selected{% endif %}">
          <a {% if variant.stock.available %} href="{{ ( product.url ~ '?id=' ~ variant.id) | url }}" {% endif %} title="{% if variant.stock.available %}{{ 'In stock' | t }}{% else %}{{ 'Out of stock' | t }}{% endif %}" class="variations">
            {% if 'Color:' in variant.title or 'Size:' in variant.title %}
              {% set splittitle = variant.title | split('","')[0] %}
              {{ splittitle | trim('"Color: ') }}
              {% set splittitle = variant.title | split('"Size: ')[1] %}
              {{ splittitle[:-1] }}
             {% elseif 'Color' in variant.title or 'Size' not in variant.title %}
              {{ variant.title | split(': ')|last }}
            {% elseif 'Size' in variant.title or 'Color' not in variant.title %}
              {{ variant.title | split(': ')|last }}
            {% endif %}
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

When I click on any of this variables of the product it changes the picture, and the prices and every feature related with the item's variable.

I would like to convert this into a drop-down menu for the variable and i did it changing the  into a  and the  into an  tag and it works on the front-end see the image below :

[image using the select and option tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b32iW.png)

This is the code when I change the tags:

```
<select class="variants dropMenu">
        {% for variant in product.variants%}
        <option class="{% if not variant.stock.available %}unavailable{% elseif variant.id == product.vid %}selected{% elseif variant.id != product.vid%}not-selected{% endif %}">
          <a {% if variant.stock.available %} href="{{ ( product.url ~ '?id=' ~ variant.id) | url }}" {% endif %} title="{% if variant.stock.available %}{{ 'In stock' | t }}{% else %}{{ 'Out of stock' | t }}{% endif %}" class="variations">
            {% if 'Color:' in variant.title or 'Size:' in variant.title %}
              {% set splittitle = variant.title | split('","')[0] %}
              {{ splittitle | trim('"Color: ') }}
              {% set splittitle = variant.title | split('"Size: ')[1] %}
              {{ splittitle[:-1] }}
             {% elseif 'Color' in variant.title or 'Size' not in variant.title %}
              {{ variant.title | split(': ')|last }}
            {% elseif 'Size' in variant.title or 'Color' not in variant.title %}
              {{ variant.title | split(': ')|last }}
            {% endif %}
          </a>
        </option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

but when I make the change the functionality stop to work.

If someone can help me fixing this I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean with "the functionality  stops to work"?

Comment: It doesn't load the variables the img or change the product title.

Comment: So you do this with javascript?